# What does a disputed flag mean?

Tags: support, flagging

Looking at my flagging history I saw that there was one "disputed" flag.

What does a disputed flag mean?

Comment: See this answer on the main meta site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/159222

Answer (score 1):

That would be a time when something was flagged, but upon review it was declined.  This in and of itself is not necessarily bad, but the system takes that into account and puts less weight on flags from users that have a high percentage of declined flags.

Comment: A disputed flag is one where a high rep user has disagreed with the flag, rather than it being declined by a moderator.  As I understand it the flag can be disputed and still acted upon by a moderator.  Disputed flags don't impact flag weight according to this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/159222

Comment: Ahh, yes I believe you are right.